# NestedScrollView not scrolling when dragging from Clickable LinearLayouts

Tags: java, android

I've implemented a NestedScrollView on my app, and inside it has some LinearLayouts that are clickable, the problem is when I'm scrolling, if I'm dragging the NestedScrollView while pressing one of those LinearLayouts it doesn't scroll. Any ideas why this might be happening?.

This is part of xml:

```
<LinearLayout
                        android:id="@+id/llclick"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_weight="1"
                        android:background="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground"
                        android:clickable="true"
                        android:orientation="horizontal"
                        android:padding="24dp">

                        <ImageView
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                            android:src="@drawable/ic_phone"
                            android:tint="@color/secondary_text"/>

                        <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/telefono"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                            android:layout_marginLeft="24dp"
                            android:layout_marginStart="24dp"
                            android:text="04166672401"
                            android:textColor="@color/primary_text"
                            android:textSize="16sp"/>

                    </LinearLayout>

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:id="@+id/llsms"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:background="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground"
                        android:clickable="true"
                        android:orientation="horizontal"
                        android:padding="24dp">

                        <ImageView
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:src="@drawable/ic_message_text"
                            android:tint="@color/secondary_text"/>

                    </LinearLayout>
```